# Command run is not the one returned by the command `which`

Tags: symlink, path, which

```
$ which doxygen
/home/gauthier/bin/doxygen
$ $(which doxygen) -v
1.8.13
$ doxygen -v
1.8.11 # <- ???
$ doxygen
error: Doxyfile not found and no input file specified!
Doxygen version 1.8.11
Copyright Dimitri van Heesch 1997-2015
# ... doxygen's help
$ type -a doxygen
doxygen is /home/gauthier/bin/doxygen
doxygen is /home/gauthier/bin/doxygen
doxygen is /usr/bin/doxygen
```

I'm trying to setup a new version of doxygen, to use in parallel to the one already on my machine.

I downloaded binaries, placed them somewhere in `/opt`, and created a symlink to them in my `~/bin`, which is in my `PATH`.

As seen in the terminal paste above, running `doxygen` does not seem to call to the same binary found by `which doxygen`.

What might be going on?

Comment: What do you get if you do `type doxygen`?

Comment: @richard 1.8.11, see my edit.

Comment: Actually, try `type -a` to see all resolutions of a command...just in case there are any like-named aliases, functions, etc.

Comment: @BLayer: added the result of `type -a doxygen`. There's a double entry, I wonder why (but probably not a problem, I guess?)

Comment: What do you see when you run `hash -t doxygen`?

Comment: Hmm. Do you have your home dir in your PATH twice? (You're right, though, that's not likely to be related to your issue.)

Comment: @EricRenouf: Ha! Only `/usr/bin/doxygen`.

Comment: @BLayer: I do have `~/bin` twice, yes. I use the same `.bashrc` on different systems, it seems that one (Ubuntu) adds `~/bin` by itself, others don't. I'm not sure where else it's added, I have it done only once in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: @richard: duplicate correct, thanks! I didn't know about hash.

Comment: @Gauthier It's pretty harmless. If it's annoying you can, of course, do a simple check for that in your path and only add conditionally in the later-loading config file(s). I do that in my own init.

Comment: @BLayer It was added in `~/.profile`, which was created by default. Apparently, Debian and brethren do this. Since I mean to use my `~/.bashrc` in other systems, I commented it out in `.profile`.

Comment: @Gauthier That works! :)

Answer (score 2):

> and created a symlink to them in my ~/bin, which is in my PATH.

The order in `PATH` is relevant. Make sure to put your personal bin dir at the start; something like this:

```
export PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
```

You should be able to see the lookup order using `which -a <command>`.

Comment: It's relevant to determine which version should run, but that can't explain that `which` and running the bin find different versions?

Comment: In any case, `/home/gauthier/bin` is early in my `PATH`.